# Nested cross-validation in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation

I need to do nested cross-validation for a machine learning project, a binary classification task where I compare LASSO and RandomForest. I typically use R for data analysis but couldn't find a function or any convenient snippet of code for nested cross-validation in R so I turned to Python. Code for nested cross-validation with Python is provided here: https://mlfromscratch.com/nested-cross-validation-python-code/#/

The (binary) variable to be predicted is labelled 'DIAG' in the dataframe. Here is the code I am using.

```
from nested_cv import NestedCV

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("model1_past_history.xlsx")

df1['DIAG'] = np.where(df1['DIAG']=='MDD', '0', '1')

conditions = [
    (df1['marital'] == 'married'),
    (df1['marital'] == 'single'),
    (df1['marital'] == 'divorced')]
choices = ['0', '1', '2']

df1['marital'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

df1.DIAG.value_counts()

df1.iloc[:,0:df1.columns.get_loc("BMI")] = df1.iloc[:,0:df1.columns.get_loc("BMI")].astype('category')


df1.info(verbose=True)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1635 entries, 0 to 1634
Data columns (total 70 columns):
DIAG                     1635 non-null category
INC2_A                   1635 non-null category
INC2_B                   1635 non-null category
INC2_F                   1635 non-null category
INC2_G                   1635 non-null category
INC2_H                   1635 non-null category
INC2_I                   1635 non-null category
SEX                      1635 non-null category
marital                  1635 non-null category
inpatient                1635 non-null category
AD_1                     1635 non-null category
AD_2                     1635 non-null category
AD_3                     1635 non-null category
AD_4                     1635 non-null category
CMS_1                    1635 non-null category
CMS_2                    1635 non-null category
CMS_3                    1635 non-null category
CMS_4                    1635 non-null category
CMS_5                    1635 non-null category
CMS_6                    1635 non-null category
CMS_7                    1635 non-null category
CMS_8                    1635 non-null category
CMS_9                    1635 non-null category
CMS_10                   1635 non-null category
CMS_11                   1635 non-null category
CMS_12                   1635 non-null category
CMS_13                   1635 non-null category
CMS_14                   1635 non-null category
OCS_1                    1635 non-null category
OCS_2                    1635 non-null category
OCS_3                    1635 non-null category
OCS_4                    1635 non-null category
OCS_5                    1635 non-null category
OCS_6                    1635 non-null category
OCS_7                    1635 non-null category
OCS_8                    1635 non-null category
OCS_9                    1635 non-null category
OCS_10                   1635 non-null category
OCS_11                   1635 non-null category
reta                     1635 non-null category
MH_F1                    1635 non-null category
CP_1BA                   1635 non-null category
CP_1BS                   1635 non-null category
MIXCLINICAL3             1635 non-null category
MIXCLINICAL2             1635 non-null category
MIXDS52Simpt             1635 non-null category
MIXDS53Simpt             1635 non-null category
PAN                      1635 non-null category
OBS                      1635 non-null category
PHO                      1635 non-null category
GAD                      1635 non-null category
EAT_0                    1635 non-null category
ADHD                     1635 non-null category
BORDERLINEPERSONALITY    1635 non-null category
AlcoolProbUse            1635 non-null category
SubstanceProbUse         1635 non-null category
BMI                      1635 non-null float64
DEP_AGE                  1635 non-null int64
NBD_P                    1635 non-null int64
NBDEP                    1635 non-null int64
NBSUI                    1635 non-null int64
NBHOS                    1635 non-null int64
DURDEP                   1635 non-null int64
SEV_M                    1635 non-null int64
SEV_D                    1635 non-null int64
CMS_sum                  1635 non-null int64
TOTMIXDSM5               1635 non-null int64
GAF                      1635 non-null int64
Age                      1635 non-null int64
Comorbidities_sum        1635 non-null int64
dtypes: category(55), float64(1), int64(14)
memory usage: 284.7 KB


X = df1.iloc[:, 1:len(df1.columns)]

y = df1.iloc[:,0]

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

from sklearn.metrics import auc

models_to_run = [RandomForestClassifier(), Lasso()]

models_param_grid = [ 
                    { # 1st param grid, corresponding to RandomForestClassifier
                            'n_estimators': [500,1000],
                            'max_features' : [8,12,16]
                    }, 
                    { # 2nd param grid, corresponding to Lasso
                            'alpha': [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10],
                    }
                    ]

for i,model in enumerate(models_to_run):
    nested_CV_search = NestedCV(model=model, params_grid=models_param_grid[i], outer_kfolds=5, inner_kfolds=5, cv_options={'sqrt_of_score':False, 'metric':auc,'metric_score_indicator_lower':False})


nested_CV_search.fit(X=X,y=y)
```

The last line of code produces this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably comes from when you get the values from the dataframe. Calling `.iloc` is not enough, but you have to call `.values` to get a numpy vector of the values inside the data frame:

```py
X = df1.iloc[:, 1:len(df1.columns)].values

y = df1.iloc[:,0].values
```

Also, I noticed that you might want `nested_CV_search.fit(X=x, y=y)` inside the for loop.

Comment: Dear @Julia K, thank you for your help. I fixed the code as you suggested, but it still throws the same error. You can find a subset of the data I am working on at the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uoOm0TqGCwA1zXqthJ_45Kk9bZCHbEBJ/view?usp=sharing , should you care to give it a try. Thanks